# ¿Como puedo redireccionar a otra activity luego de regresar del bloqueo de pantalla u otra app?

Tags: android

Tengo una app sencilla con un login, lo que deseo es que en "x" número de activies cuando el usuario cambie de aplicación o el se bloquee la pantalla al regresar al app regrese a un activity en especifico (el login).
Por ejemplo: Estoy en el app en el activity "A" y en el metodo onStart() o al recuperar la visibilidad del activity "A" pero solo si viene de un bloqueo de pantalla o recupera el primer plano el app me mande al activity de "B" (el login) y no al "A".

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre esta que idea que es la más sencilla, detectando cuando la pantalla ha sido bloqueada:

Agregamos una variable para validar si fue bloqueada la pantalla y otra para validar cuando se cambio de aplicación:

```
 private boolean seBloqueoPantalla;
 private boolean cambioAplicacion;
```

dentro de `onPause()` cambiamos el valor de la variable `seBloqueoPantalla` a "true", si detectamos bloqueo de pantalla:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    boolean isScreenOn = powerManager.isScreenOn();
    if (!isScreenOn) {
        Log.i(TAG, "La pantalla ha sido bloqueada");
        seBloqueoPantalla = true;
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

y por medio del método `onStop()` cambiamos el valor de la variable `cambioAplicacion` a "true", si detectamos que cambiamos de la aplicación:

```
   @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        cambioAplicacion = true;
        super.onStop();
    }
```

Mediante el metodo `onResume()` se puede realizar un intent a la actividad "login", dependiendo del estado de la variable `seBloqueoPantalla` y  `cambioAplicacion` :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if(seBloqueoPantalla && cambioAplicacion) {
        //Redirecciona a la actividad Login!.
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        //reiniciamos valores.
        seBloqueoPantalla = false; 
        cambioAplicacion = false;
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: Excelente, funciona muy bien cuando se bloquea la pantalla pero en el caso cuando cambio de app y regreso, como puedo detectar eso?

Comment: @MichaelEmirReynosaBeltran he editado mi respuesta, saludos!

Comment: Funciona incluso solamente colocar la variable global "cambioAplicación" y ponerla en true en el onStop() pero por ejemplo al regresar con el botón fisico también se activa y se va al "LoginActivity", si hubiera forma de saber que la activity paró porq se cambio de aplicación o se bloqueo la pantalla seria genial.

Comment: Lo que necesito es algo así como el "clearTaskOnLaunch" pero no entiendo porque no me funciona. Que cuando el usuario salga del app por A o B motivo al regresar me lleve al Login y no a la pantalla donde se quedó. Saludos.

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html